# OSX: can I dd a usb thumb drive into a file?

Tags: macos, usb-storage, dd

I have mounted a usb thumb drive into my MBP.

Here is the partial output from `mount`

```
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/KINGSTON (ntfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

When I tried

```
$ dd if=/dev/disk2s1 of=usb.img bs=512
dd: /dev/disk2s1: Resource busy
```

It seems like 'Resource busy' error prevent me from using `dd` on the thumb drive.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Disk Utility to unmount the drive, and possibly also to do the copy; this has the advantage that you can mount the image afterward if you need to get at any files in it.  If you prefer the command line, `hdiutil` is the command line version of Disk Utility.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe unmount usb drive first and then rerun dd?

Answer (score 1):

Unmount the volume after you learn its device, then repeat.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X (Yosemite) use:
`sudo diskutil unmount /dev/[your device]`